# Dotnet test task fails with ''MSB1008: Only one project can be specified" error after upgrade to version 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs, tfsbuild

The TFS instance I am working on was recently upgraded from TFS 2017 Update 1 to TFS 2018 Update 2, allowing me to change the dotnet task version used in my build definitions from 0.* to 2.*.

In doing so, the dotnet test step no longer works, returning the following error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: trx
```

The command it runs is:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test <Agent_WorkFolder>\1\w\3\s\source\MySolution\MyProject.csproj --configuration release --logger trx --logger trx --results-directory <Agent_WorkFolder>\1\w\_temp
```

The parameters given to the task are:

- Paths to projects = `**\*Tests*.csproj`
- Arguments = `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --logger trx`

Reverting the task version back to 0.*, and it runs again. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is caused by `--logger trx` being specified in the Arguments to the task. The newer versions of the task automatically adds this switch when executing the `dotnet test` command as its the output which TFS supports for reading test results. The extra argument results in the switch being given twice, so whilst MSBUILD error is unhelpful, the `Switch: trx` part gives a clue as to what is the problem.

Removing the switch from the arguments resolved the problem.

Comment: I tried running dotnet test "Solution.sln" and I still get the error

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, I suggest you raise a new question with the complete command and log output that is returned (like my question) to get the help you require.

Comment: I just went with defining them manually. Too much of a hastle

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this could also happen if you've got a space in one of the arguments, then it thinks there are multiple args

Comment: Solution then is to put the arg between qoutes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).